# Set up SSL/Certificate for seperate server

Tags: wcf, ssl, https, dns, ssl-certificate

I am new to SSL，here I have a question about how to set up SSL/certificate.

Our web site is hosted on server A(Windows server 2003 with IIS6), we also have a WCF web service that is used by the web site to get data from database, and this service is hosted on Server B(Windows server 2003 with IIS6).

So how to setup SSL/Certificate to make sure that the client server communication is encrypted? do I need to apply 2 certificate for each server?

I also have a very fundamental question, say my server's ip address is 192.168.0.5, it has multiple ports for different application, for example 8090, so which one is called domain? 192.168.0.5? or 192.168.0.5.8090?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both server are running IIS 6, you can just export your certificate as PFX and install it on the other server.

Following sites might be helpful:

Export:
https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1231880-back-up-certificate---internet-information-services-iis-7
http://www.sslshopper.com/move-or-copy-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-windows-server-to-another-windows-server.html

Installation:
https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1290320-install-certificate---internet-information-services-iis-5-6
http://www.sslshopper.com/microsoft-iis-5-and-6-ssl-installation-instructions.html

Hope this helps!